# Piwik track which user access which page

Tags: javascript, matomo

I want to use Piwik to trace which user stays on which page in my rails app but I cannot figure out how to trace it. I added a custom variable (page scope) but in Piwik I only see the `user_id` and its count of visits but not which pages. Also, I got url based view but not for which user. Anybody knows how to deal with this? Also I can not use custom Dimension because my Piwik version is older and I can not upgrade it now. I tried `setUserId` option as well but no luck.

My code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _paq = _paq || [];
  _paq.push(['setCustomVariable', 1, "user_id", "<%= current_user.id %>", "page" ]);
  _paq.push(['setUserId', '<%= current_user.id %>']);
  _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
  _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
  _paq.push(['enableHeartBeatTimer']);

  (function() {
    var u="//myserver/piwik/";
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', 1]);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
  })();
</script>
<noscript><p><img src="//myserver/piwik/piwik.php?idsite=1" style="border:0;" alt="" /></p></noscript>
<!-- End Piwik Code -->
```

Comment: So the custom variable with scope page does not appear in the tooltip when you hover on the page URL or page title in Piwik's visitor log as explained at http://piwik.org/docs/custom-variables/? Have you checked what's inside the database?

Comment: I can see but I not getting how to fetch data through ajax request: which user visits which pages and for how long. Also I tried with setUserId. Is there any linking in userId and visitorId? I can access data through method Live.getVisitorProfile

Comment: Use  a browsers developers tools to view the HTTP requests set to  Piwik, and what is being sent?